# FInd maximun in a List of List

Tags: prolog

I have a list of list like this:

```
matrix_max([[1, 2, 3], [8, 1, 4], [3, 5, 9]], Max).
```

I need to determine the maximum value between all the lists ( Max = 9 ).

I don't understand How can I do to check the value in other lists thant the first.

```
// there i found the max value of a list
my_max([], R, R). 
my_max([X|Xs], WK, R):- X >  WK, my_max(Xs, X, R). 
my_max([X|Xs], WK, R):- X =< WK, my_max(Xs, WK, R).
my_max([X|Xs], R):- my_max(Xs, X, R). 


// then I should control the maximum value for all the lists.
matrix_max([Head | Rest], Max) :-
    matrix_max([Head | Rest], 0, Max).

matrix_max([Head | Rest], Value, Max) :-
    my_max(Head, Max_List),
    Max_List > Value, 
    Max is Max_List,
    matrix_max(Rest,Max_List, Max).
```

How can I do?

Thank you

EDIT1.

So my code is:

```
matrix_max([], Max, Max).
matrix_max([Head | Rest], Value, Max) :-
    my_max(Head, Max_List), 
    Max is max(Max_List, Value),
    matrix_max(Rest,Max_List, Max).

matrix_max([Head | Rest], Max) :-
    my_max(Head, M),
    matrix_max(Rest, M, Max).

 my_max([X|L], M) :-
    my_max(L, X, M).

my_max([], R, R). 
my_max([X|Xs], WK, R):-
    V is max(X, WK),
    my_max(Xs, V, R).
```

I tried this: matrix_max([[1, 2, 3], [8, 1, 4], [3, 5, 9]], Max).

false.

Comment: You do not specify a case for `Max_List <= Value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify a casee for `Max_List <= Value`. But you do not need to *branch* for the two cases. Prolog's [**`is/2`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(is)/2) can evaluate an expression with `max(…, …)``, indeed:

```
?- M is max(1,2).
M = 2.
```

We thus can calculate the maximum of the `Max_list` and `Value`:

```
matrix_max([], Max, Max).
matrix_max([Head | Rest], Value, Max) :-
    my_max(Head, Max_List), 
    MaxCur is max(Max_List, Value),
    matrix_max(Rest, MaxCur, Max).
```

The `matrix_max/2` predicate can not use `0` as initial accumulator, since the values can all be smaller than zero. You should first call `my_max/2` on the first row:

```
matrix_max([Head | Rest], Max) :-
    my_max(Head, M),
    matrix_max(Rest, M, Max).
```

You furthermore need to cover the case where the list is empty, so the first clause.

In a similar way you can simplify `my_max/3`:

```
my_max([X|L], M) :-
    my_max(L, X, M).

my_max([], R, R). 
my_max([X|Xs], WK, R):-
    V is max(X, WK),
    my_max(Xs, V, R).
```

You can implement both `my_max` and `matrix_max` as a "*fold* pattern" with [**`foldl/4`**](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=foldl/4):

```
max2(X1, X2, M) :-
    M is max(X1, X2).

my_max([X|Xs], M) :-
    my_max(Xs, X, M).

my_max(Xs, M0, M) :-
    foldl(max2, Xs, M0, M).

matrix_max([R|Rs], M) :-
    my_max(R, RM),
    foldl(my_max, Rs, RM, M).
```

Comment: Thank you for you help, I have correct my code with you suggest, but I receive an error. I edited the message.

Comment: @Jack23: you apparently removed (did not specify) a definition for `matrix_max/3` (so with three parameters), as in the second code fragment.

Comment: Thank you so much! you are right, I have correct my code, I have tried with a list of list and the result is False.

Comment: @Jack23: you did at the `matrix_max([], Max, Max).` at the top (so with the empty list)?

Comment: @Jack23: sorry, made a typo.

Comment: Thank you  so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer:-

```
max([],0).
max([H|T],Max):-
    max(T,TMax),
    H>TMax,
    Max is H.
max([H|T],Max):-
    max(T,TMax),
    H=<TMax,
    Max is TMax.

matrix_max(List, Max):-
    findall(V1,member([V1,_,_],List),V1List),
    findall(V2,member([_,V2,_],List),V2List),
    findall(V3,member([_,_,V3],List),V3List),
    append(V1List,V2List,VR1),
    append(V3List,VR1,VR2),
    max(VR2,Max).

?- matrix_max([[1, 2, 3], [8, 1, 4], [3, 5, 9]], Max).
Max = 9

?- matrix_max([[1, 2, 3], [8, 1, 4], [3, 5, 9], [5,8,66]], Max).
Max = 66
```